# HTTP Status 500 - can't create directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lucee

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, nginx, coldfusion, lucee

I'm new to Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)and working on trying to setup Lucee 5, Ubuntu, Tomcat, and nginx.  I feel like I'm close to it working, but getting this error 500 when going to the page (sometestfile.cfm) in my browser.

HTTP Status 500 - can't create directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lucee

Any idea on how to resolve this error?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: can't create directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lucee
lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.getConfigDirectory(CFMLEngineImpl.java:650)
lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.loadJSPFactory(CFMLEngineImpl.java:584)
lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.addServletConfig(CFMLEngineImpl.java:537)
lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineWrapper.addServletConfig(CFMLEngineWrapper.java:89)
lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineFactory.getInstance(CFMLEngineFactory.java:207)
lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.init(CFMLServlet.java:44)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
mod_cfml.core.invoke(core.java:247)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 6):

It will be a permission issue. The user that Tomcat is running as needs permission to write to the ROOT directory so it can create the WEB-INF directory. Or create the WEB-INF for it and then change the owner to the user that Tomcat is running as, using the chown command.

e.g.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF
sudo chown tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF
```

where tomcat is the user that tomcat is running as.